# cakepdf not found engine on shared hosting

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

my app is throwing " Pdf engine "CakePdf.allengines" not found " but in my local is all fine, im using  a shared hosting plan and all the app is working fine but cakepdf is the only plugin that Im using.

Other thing is that the mpdf or dompdf files are located in verdor folder, so i dont know where cakephp is looking for the engines in the shared hosting.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you do composer update on the live server?

Comment: Make sure that you upload your entire vendor directory as it contains the components necessary to load CakePdf and its engines. One of the files that you can't miss is for example `cakephp-plugins.php`.

Comment: Hi, I cant use composer directly on the shared hosting, and i have uploaded all vendor folder, and all the other components are working fine.